# Django-tenant “No tenant for hostname” error

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I was able to create a schema (and I confirmed this via database) but for some reason, I am getting a `Can't create tenant outside the public schema. Current schema is` error when creating schema and then also I am getting this error `No tenant for hostname` when I try to visit the tenants domain and I am not sure what is causing it. Below is my code:

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request):
        form = CreatePortalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            getDomain = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            user_id = request.user.id
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            tenant = Client(schema_name=getDomain, name=getDomain, created_by=user)
            tenant.save()
            domain = Domain()
            domain.domain = getDomain + ".example.com:8000"
            domain.tenant = tenant
            domain.is_primary = True
            domain.save()

            with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
                instance.save()
                redirect = 'http://' + getDomain + '.example.com:8000'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
        return render(request, "registraton/create_portal.html", {"form": form})
```

For example, I have created three schemas:

1. tenant1
2. tenant2
3. tenant3

All three tenants have created the tables in the database, but I get the  `Can't create tenant outside the public schema. Current schema is` error when running the above script to create the schema and domain or I get the `No tenant for hostname` when trying to visit the tenants domain.

Like I said, the schema is creating and migrating successfully but I still cannot get to the domain.example.com as it throws the `No tenant for hostname` error. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The django-tenants docs says that you shouldn't specify the port for your domain.

See this [here](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#:%7E:text=domain.domain%20%3D%20%27my%2Ddomain.com%27%20%23%20don%27t%20add%20your%20port%20or%20www%20here!%20on%20a%20local%20server%20you%27ll%20want%20to%20use%20localhost%20here)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33362337)